# Remove escape from string c#

Tags: c#

I have a path in my network who I can use in File Explorer without problems:

```
\\MyNetwork\Projects\16000
```

Now I want to access it using `Directory.Exists` as:

```
var normalFolderPath = @"\MyNetwork";
var number = @"\16000"


var a = Directory.Exists($@"{normalFolderPath}\{number}");
```

But this: `$@"{normalFolderPath}\{number}"` return `\\MyNetwork\\16000` but if I try to access it that on File Explorer just can not found, but if I remove `\` from subfolder like: `\\MyNetwork\16000` it works!, how can I remove one `\` from `string` in `c#`

Comment: why not switch to `Path.Combine`?

Comment: I try it, but same result `\\MyNetwork\\16000` @DanielA.White

Comment: You could use `Trim` to clean that up.

Comment: Why are you doing `{normalFolderPath}\{number}`? Why not `\\{normalFolderPath}\\{number}`? There's no reason to include a backslash inside of the `normalFolderPath` string _or_ the `number` string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're complaining that your string has two slashes in the middle of it, but you put two slashes in the middle of it:

- `number` is the literal string `\16000`
- You asked c# to concatenate `normalfolderpath` with `number`, separated by slash: `{normalFolderPath}\{number}`

Naturally, you'll end up with two slashes; one from number, and one as the separator. To demo what I mean, here is an altered code:

```
var normalFolderPath = @"\MyNetwork";
var number = @"!16000"


var a = Directory.Exists($@"{normalFolderPath}={number}");
```

This will produce the string `\MyNetwork=!16000`: the `=` is the separator between the interpolated fields and `!` came from the start of `number`

> But this: `$@"{normalFolderPath}\{number}"` return `\\MyNetwork\\16000`

I disagree: it will definitely return `\MyNetwork\\16000` with only one slash at the start and two in the middle. No way will that code you put, return something with two slashes at the start

---

As has been commented, you should use `Path.Combine` to combine path elements:

```
var normalFolderPath = @"\\MyNetwork";
var number = "16000"


var a = Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(normalFolderPath,number));
```